# How do convert a whole RSS feed into a PDF?

Tags: rss, pdf

I want to take a blog and make a PDF out of the RSS feed so I can save it somewhere for offline viewing.

I want to save every single post into the PDF.

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [xFruits](http://www.xfruits.com/)
  [image: Screenshot of xFruits]
- [FeedJournal](http://www.feedjournal.com/Reader.aspx)

  [image: Screenshot of FeedJournal]
- [FiveFilters PDF Newspaper](http://fivefilters.org/pdf-newspaper/)

  [image: Screenshot of FiveFilters PDF Newspaper]
  <sub>(source: [webresourcesdepot.com](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/image/rss-to-pdf.jpg))</sub>
- [A Google gadget](http://www.mt-soft.com.ar/2007/12/21/rss-atom-to-pdf-conversion-google-gadget/)

  [image: Screenshot of gadget]
- [RSS2PDF](http://rss2pdf.org/)
- [RSS2](http://www.rss2.co.uk/) can generate a PDF from
  multiple feeds

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

http://rss2pdf.com/

Comment: I've already tried it but it doesn't download all the posts, but only a portion of them (latest 5 posts or something).

Comment: If you go to any blog you can paginate between the HTML posts, but RSS seems to be stuck at the latest 10 or so, and you can't seem to paginate through RSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could just view the RSS feed in your browser (as long as it formats it relatively nicely, which [Internet Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/) actually seems to do better than [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/) or [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/) - *shock*!) and then print it to a PDF using something like [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of Blog is it ?

Do you want comments as well ?

Is it your blog ?

I have also heard of individuals using this feature to create e-books which they sell (of which content does not originally belong to them)  The better ones that extract most if not all the posts seems to be those that allow the owner of the blog this feature in the case of [BlogBooker](http://www.blogbooker.com) / [LJ Book](http://www.ljbook.com/)

More reliable public services come from [Tabbloid](http://www.tabbloid.com/) by HP which offer you a digest (like a newspaper) to your email based on a frequency of your choosing. In this case you get the most updated content.

The most reasonable in your case will be [FeedBooks](http://www.feedbooks.com/) NewsPaper Option. But then again the number of items you want to collect will be based on your RSS feed limit no ? ( in the case of BlogBooker you are able to use your Blog Export as xml )  Maybe just maybe you can get around this by playing with the feeds, grabbing in batches or the sorts. For example this Newspaper [Gizmodo Feed](http://www.feedbooks.com/newspaper/3798) only gives a few items (the most recent) as a [PDF](http://www.feedbooks.com/newspaper/3798.pdf)

Comment: Just any regular blog, no comments.  Seems like RSS just gives you a limit (say 10-15 latest posts) and there's no way to paginate there unlike via HTML.